# Mongoose DBRef implementation is not the same like in MongoDB documentation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have big problem with maybe trivial problem. I'm trying to use `reference` with mongoose.js for MongoDB database. Let's take a look on this example:

### Example code:

https://gist.github.com/hastebrot/1170907

When I run this code I have something like that in my db:

```
> db.stories.find()
{ 
  "title" : "A man who cooked Nintendo",
  "_creator" :  ObjectId("52e7dc001bdedb703df29b8e"),
  "_id" : ObjectId("52e7dc001bdedb703df29b8f"),
  "fans" : [ ], "__v" : 0
}

> db.people.find()
{
  "name" : "Aaron",
  "age" : 100,
  "_id" : ObjectId("52e7dc001bdedb703df29b8e"),
  "stories" : [ ], "__v" : 0
}
```

### Where is the problem?

In case where I insert data using mongoose and read references using mongoose all is fine. **But** when db is fetched by Java program with own layer for mongoDB then problem appear.

This Java program add something like that into db (this is another example don't look on not matched field):

```
//other fields
"user": {
    "$ref": "users",
    "$id": {
        "$oid": "52c6c497c08e6fcf37000001"
    }
}
```

When we go to documentation of MongoDB (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) we can read that reference property need `$ref` and `$id` fields.

### Question:

So is it problem with wrong implementation mongoDB DBRef type into mongoose or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference in mongoose is a manual reference, not a `dbref` (the use of which I will discuss later).  At a high level what is going on here is that it is embedding the `ObjectId` of the person as the value in the `_creator` field.  Then, should you wish to "use" that relationship, say by looking for all stories created by the person named "Aaron", there will effectively be two queries:

- 1st query will fetch the `_id` of the person names Aaron from the people collection, that is: `db.people.findOne({"name" : "Aaron"})`
- 2nd query will use that `_id` to look up all stories with that creator, that is: `db.stories.find({"creator" : ObjectId("52e7dc001bdedb703df29b8e")})`

The [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (mongoose in this case) is abstracting this for you, and allowing you to define relationships etc. without you having to be aware of what is going on under the covers.

When you are attempting to do this with a native driver outside the ORM you've made a fundamental mistake in terms of how it actually achieves these relationships.  It does not use database references, and in general their use is discouraged (see the first note about manual references in [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#database-references)), rather it uses something similar to what I described above.

If you wish to emulate the functionality, you should do something similar, and avoid the use of database references.

Comment: Ok. I understand you but I'm worried how to use these documents with references when db is feeded by Java application and create another structure than mongoose.

Comment: Either you need to emulate mongoose references, or you need to come up with a compatible schema between the two access methods.  Likely the only realistic way to absolutely maintain compatibility is to implement your required references outside of mongoose using the node.js native driver and maintain them yourself.  Otherwise, even if you emulate mongoose in Java, any changes in mongoose (upgrades) could break your java access and vice versa.